# Nest or combine extras_require for setuptools in setup.cfg

Tags: python, setuptools, dependency-management

Is it possible to re-use dependencies already specified in the `[options.extras_require]` for other entries in the `[options.extras_require]`? Say, for example, a team of devs is using `mypy` to check their type annotations during development, and `black` to auto-format their code. in this case, they would specify the `[options.extras_require]` like:

```
[options.extras_require]
dev = black, mypy
```

But now a testing environment is set-up, which also uses `mypy` to check type hints, but doesn't need `black`. So the config is extended to look like:

```
[options.extras_require]
test = mypy
dev = black, mypy
```

Now any testing-dependency also needed for development is repeated for the development-dependencies.

Is there any way to avoid this by saying that `dev` requires all in `test` as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make a reference to the extra package:

```
[metadata]
name = foo

[options.extras_require]
test = mypy
dev = black; foo[test]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! works like a charm, and is exactly what I was looking for. Just out of curiosity: how do you know? I haven't been able to find this in the docs. Thanks again!

Comment: @hintze great ! Exactly I didn't find this scenario explicitly in the documentation either so it required some experimentation