# Creating a `full' option for extras_require by combining all other options

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I have a package with a few optional dependencies defined in `setup.cfg` as:

```
[options]
...
install_requires = 
    scikit-learn>=1.0.2
    torch>=1.10.*
    torchinfo>=1.6.5
    torchvision>=0.11.*
    Pillow>=7.1.2   
    tqdm>=4.63.*
    sentencepiece>=0.1.96

[options.extras_require]
azure = 
    azure-storage-blob >= 12.13.0
metrics = 
    torchmetrics >= 0.9.3
```

How can I refer back to these if I want to create a "full" installation option that installs the core packages, as well as the `azure` option and the `metrics` option?

Comment: You can do it with [`setup.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64791668/7976758) but not with `setup.cfg`. Not everything that's possible in `setup.py` code also possible in simple `setup.cfg` key/value declarations.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70983864/4331772), it is possible to do this in `setup.cfg` by referring to the extra packages:

```
[metadata]
name = mypackage

[options.extras_require]
azure = 
    azure-storage-blob >= 12.13.0
metrics = 
    torchmetrics >= 0.9.3
full =
    mypackage[azure]
    mypackage[metrics]
```